# Change the output device for AVAudioPlayer on OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I need to play audio from AVAudioPlayer to a particular audio device such as a USB headset. By default the audio will get played out to the system default device setting.  With QTKit, I was able to use SetMovieAudioContext() to do such a task but do not see equivalent in AVFoundation. How is it possible to change this on OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [NSSound](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSound_Class/) instead:

Get list of audio devices with `CoreAudio` functions. Then get the devices' unique identifiers:

```
//...
address.mSelector = kAudioDevicePropertyDeviceUID;
CFStringRef uid = NULL;
UInt32 size = sizeof(uid);
AudioObjectGetPropertyData(deviceId, &address, 0, NULL, &size, &uid);
//...
```

Initialize sound item, set `playbackDeviceIdentifier` property value.

Comment: Thanks -  this was the approach we took.

Answer (score 1):

Opened a DTS case with Apple and they said it was not possible (as i need to support 10.8). If you only need to support 10.9 and above AVPlayerAudioDeviceSupport should work.